# How to write the following code from VB.NET to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

Code is:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Dim item As HtmlElementCollection
        item = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
        Dim ht As HtmlElement
        For Each ht In item
            MsgBox(ht.DomElement.attributes("class").value.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

In C#, it does not find the `.attributes("class").value.ToString()` part.

Comment: Off the top of my head, C# indexers use square brackets, so `attributes["class"]`... Not tested or checked.

Comment: This question is not a "please convert my code" question but OP is trying to solve a legitimate problem arising when converting to C# (he has done the conversion himself and hit a wall). Please consider removing the downvotes

Comment: @DanVerdolino Finally, someone that understood my problem. Anyway, it doesn't bother me that much, some people really enjoy down voting 3 seconds after the question has been asked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code works in VB.Net and not in C# is that you are using `Option Strict Off` (perhaps implicitly by omitting `Option Strict On`). This tells the compiler to assume there will be an `Attributes` member in the `DOMElement`, which is an `Object`.

In C# there is no equivalent to `Option Strict On` in general but if you use the `dynamic` type you can do the same thing.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
    foreach(HtmlElement ht in item)
    {
        dynamic element = ht.DomElement;
        MessageBox.Show(element.Attributes["class"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

This allows you to access properties of types you don't know at design-time as long as they will exist at run-time, similar to `Object` in VB.Net with `Option Strict Off`. Be careful though, since this allows you to write code somewhat recklessly (similar to VB :) so you should add some checking and exception handling in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Form1

{

private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection item = default(HtmlElementCollection);
    item = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
    HtmlElement ht = default(HtmlElement);
    foreach ( ht in item) {
        Interaction.MsgBox(ht.DomElement.attributes("class").value.ToString);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct value would be here:

```
ht.GetAttribute("class")
```

The Complete Code:

```
HtmlElementCollection items;
items = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
HtmlElement ht;
foreach (ht in items) {
    MessageBox.Show(ht.GetAttribute("class"));
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. It gives me "System.__COMObject" instead of the actual strinh. So I am looking to do it via DomElement as in Visual Basic .NET

Answer (score 0):

Your 'foreach' loop needs to have the variable type included in C#:

```
foreach (HtmlElement ht in item)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ht.DomElement.Attributes["class"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Also, since the 'DomElement' property of the HtmlElement class returns 'Object', you'll have to cast "ht.DomElement" to the appropriate type before invoking the 'Attributes' property. I just guessed that it was an indexer, but since 'DomElement' returns Object, it's just that - a guess.

e.g.,

```
foreach (HtmlElement ht in item)
{
    MessageBox.Show((SomeType)(ht.DomElement).Attributes["class"].Value.ToString());
}
```